# Javascript multiple script src

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a javascript file which creates a openheatmap. I need to include two different javascript src files but what I am currently doing is not working, this is what I am doing now.

```html
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://static.openheatmap.com/scripts/jquery.openheatmap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: That is the correct way to include multiple scripts. You would be better to post a [short, self contained, correct example](http://sscce.org/) of your problem. Also, jQuery 1.4.2? Kind of old don't you think?

Comment: the third ending script tag is at the bottom of my file, after those three lines I have the remaining javascript code. And yes I agree it is an old version.

Comment: If it is 'not working' it is most likely that you have a javascript error that is preventing all of your script from running. If you run the page with a developer console open it should show any errors.

Comment: *Is there a better way to do this?* No, that's the way to do it. If "it is not working" for you (whatever that means) that it is a problem with something we cannot infer from this piece of code or the little information you provided.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a better way to include JavaScript files - you do it late in your file, especially where the script is not hosted by you. This allows the page to load without being blocked loading external resources.

So I would recommend you put all scripts just before the closing `body` tag.

You can even take this a stage further and load the scripts without blocking the page rendering, which you can do with the defer attribute (which unlike the async attribute guarantees the order of execution, which looks important in your example).

```
    <script defer src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="http://static.openheatmap.com/scripts/jquery.openheatmap.js"></script>
    <script defer>
        // JavaScript here...
    </script>
</body>
```

You can also use an onload attribute with the defer attribute to specify a method to run once the DOM is ready.

```
<script defer onload="MyStuff.domLoaded();">
```

For the other part of your question, regarding whether your script works, please supply some more information.